# Will public thumbprint change on renewing a certificate?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a certificate for one year with PublicKey A, and ThumbPrint B.
As long as I know, the ThumbPrint is generated by a hash algorithm from A.

If I regenerate the certificate again with PublicKey A, the ThumbPrint should not change and will be B, right?

Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is incorrect. Certificate thumbprint is calculated over entire certificate, not just public key. When you renew the certificate, it is changed. At least, validity period will be different as the result, thumbprint on renewed certificate will be different as well.