# Generating same fingerprints across renewal

Tags: ssl-certificate, sha256, renewal, rsa-sha256

If we need to have the same sha 256 hash on renewal for our ssl certificate, is it possible ? if yes what are the steps ?
because based on my research I found out that Changing the expiry date of a certificate will indeed result in a different fingerprint, since the fingerprint is a cryptographic hash of the entire certificate's content, including the expiry date.

but i have found some mixed reviews that i can also be possible, therefore if some
cryptographic expert can can confirm this that would be awesome.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will public thumbprint change on renewing a certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119765/will-public-thumbprint-change-on-renewing-a-certificate)